# Asp .net bug happening only in when not debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

So, I have a gridview in which I add line dynamically based on user's choice. One of the cells is a custom controls which is an input with a jquery autocomplete plugging (a drop down list). A feature I have is to be able to fill this input by scanning a barcode. It does a postback and reloads everything in the page fine, with the newly scanned article in the custom control. The only exception being that it only works completely if I am debug (aka have a breakpoint in my code) or I have the Google Chrome inspector open, looking at the 'bugged' hidden field. This hidden field value, which I set on the rebinding of my gridview, will stay empty if I am not doing the things I mentionned above. Weirdest bug I have encountered so far..

Here is some code:

```
protected void gv_OnItemDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var assetcombobox = (e.Row.FindControl("assetcombobox") as global.assetcomboboxv2);
        var asset = AssetDAL.GetItem(args[0].GetInt());//args is what the scanner returns
        assetcombobox.SelectedValue = asset.Id;
    }
}
```

Setting the assetcombobox selected value like this fills the input and other values in my code, including (supposedly) the hidden field so It finds the asset and everything.. It just won't set the hidden field to a value outside of debugging.

Comment: This kind of problem is something you should discuss with your fellow developers if you work in a team. There really isn't enough details for the online community to help you on this. First time I've read a problem like this and the only thing I can think of that can have this kind of impact are the [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) such as `#if DEBUG`.

Comment: You are probably right, I found a workaround but I'll keep you comment in mind when talking of this to my team! thanks for your time.